# from for loop to apply

Tags: r, loops, statistics, apply

I am new in using R.
So I am not sure about how to use apply.
I would like to speed up my function with using apply:

```
for(i in 1: ncol(exp)){
 for (j in 1: length(fe)){
  tmp =TRUE
  id = strsplit(colnames(exp)[i],"\\.")
  if(id == fe[j]){
   tmp = FALSE
  }
  if(tmp ==TRUE){
   only = cbind(only,c(names(exp)[i],exp[,i]) )
  }
 }
}
```

How can I use the apply function to do this above?

EDIT :

Thank you so much for the very good explanation and sorry for my bad description. You guess everything right, but When wanted to delete matches in fe.

```
Exp <- data.frame(A.x=1:10,B.y=10:1,C.z=11:20,A.z=20:11)

fe<-LETTERS[1:2]
```

then the result should be only colnames with 'C'. Everything else should be deleted.

```
1   C.z 
2    11 
3    12   
4    13   
5    14 
6    15  
7    16  
8    17  
9    18   
10   19  
11   20
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of what `exp` and `fe` look like? Either make up a trivial example, or post the contents of the objects with `dput(exp)` and `dput(fe)`.

Comment: **Never** grow an object in a loop like that with your `cbind()` --- allocate the storage up front and fill in the object. That said - provide us with the output @Chase requests and we can see about providing a non-loop-based alternative(s).

Answer (score 4):

EDIT : If you only want to delete the columns whose name appear in fe, you can simply do :

```
Exp <- data.frame(A.x=1:10,B.y=10:1,C.z=11:20,A.z=20:11)
fe<-LETTERS[1:2]

id <- sapply(strsplit(names(Exp),"\\."),
    function(i)!i[1] %in% fe)
Exp[id]
```

This code does exactly what your (updated) for-loop does as well, only a lot more efficient. You don't have to loop through fe, the `%in%` function is vectorized.

In case the name can appear anywhere between the dots, then

```
id <- sapply(strsplit(names(Exp),"\\."),
    function(i)sum(i %in% fe)==0)
```

---

Your code does some very funny things, and I have no clue what exactly you're trying to do. For one, `strsplit` gives a list, so `id == fe[j]` will always return false, unless `fe[j]` is a list itself. And I doubt it is... So I'd correct your code as

```
id = strsplit(colnames(Exp)[i],"\\.")[[1]][1]
```

in case you want to compare with everything that is before the dot, or to

```
id = unlist(strsplit(colnames(Exp)[i],"\\."))
```

if you want to compare with everything in the string. In that case, you should use `%in%`instead of `==` as well.

Second, what you get is a character matrix, which essentially multiplies rows. if all elements in fe[j] are unique, you could as well do :

```
only <- rbind(names(exp),exp)
only <- do.call(cbind,lapply(mat,function(x) 
       matrix(rep(x,ncol(exp)-1),nrow=nrow(exp)+1)
))
```

Assuming that the logic in your code does make sense (as you didn't apply some sample data this is impossible to know), the optimalization runs :

```
mat <- rbind(names(Exp),Exp)

do.call(cbind,
    lapply(mat, function(x){
        n <- sum(!fe %in% strsplit(x[1],"\\.")[[1]][1])
        matrix(rep(x,n),nrow=nrow(mat))
}))
```

Note that - in case you are interested if fe[j] appears anywhere in the name - you can change the code to :

```
do.call(cbind,
    lapply(mat, function(x){
        n <- sum(!fe %in% unlist(strsplit(x[1],"\\.")))
        matrix(rep(x,n),nrow=nrow(mat))
}))
```

If this doesn't return what you want, then your code doesn't do that either. I checked with following sample data, and all gives the same result :

```
Exp <- data.frame(A.x=1:10,B.y=10:1,C.z=11:20,A.z=20:11)
fe <- LETTERS[1:4]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  i found my solution, but I not familiar in using apply? So I used for loop. I would be helpful to get a hind how to use apply for this: 'Exp <- data.frame(A.x=1:10,B.y=10:1,C.z=11:20,A.z=20:11)
fe <- LETTERS[1:2]
n=c()



for(i in 1: ncol(Exp)){
 for (j in 1: length(fe)){
    if (fe[j] %in% unlist(strsplit(colnames(Exp[i]),"\\.")[[1]][1])){
     n = c(n,i)
    }
  }
}

newExp= Exp[-n]'

Comment: @cirrus : It's in my answer, the first piece of code. That's the apply equivalent of your loop. You forget about vectorization in R, which is done within the loop by using the %in% function. There is no need whatsoever to loop over all elements of fe. Check that code again, read the help files and try to figure out what it does. You had the answer in front of you the whole time.

Comment: @cirrus : you're welcome. If you consider this answer the correct one, you can indicate it using the V sign on the left. See also the FAQ of this site. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The `apply()` family of functions are convenience functions.  They will not necessarily be faster than a well-written for loop or vectorized functions.  For example:

```
set.seed(21)
x <- matrix(rnorm(1e6),5e5,2)

system.time({
  yLoop <- x[,1]*0  # preallocate result
  for(i in 1:NROW(yLoop)) yLoop[i] <- mean(x[i,])
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   13.39    0.00   13.39 
system.time(yApply <- apply(x, 1, mean))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   16.19    0.28   16.51
system.time(yRowMean <- rowMeans(x))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.02    0.00    0.02
identical(yLoop,yApply,yRowMean)
# TRUE
```

The reason your code is so slow is that--as Gavin pointed out--you're growing your array for every loop iteration.  Preallocate the entire array before the loop and you will see a significant speedup.